# No centre alignment in columns defined by tabular despite defining specifically in header

Tags: tables, multirow, multicolumn, wrap

I have a document like:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
 \usepackage{array,ltablex,makecell}% ltablex loads tabularx and longtable also
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize\bfseries}
 \newenvironment{conditions}
 {\par\vspace{\abovedisplayskip}\noindent\begin{tabular}{>{$}l<{$} @{${}={}$} l}}
 {\end{tabular}\par\vspace{\belowdisplayskip}}%This is for descriptions of equations
\usepackage[]{multirow}%Essential for cells in table spanning multiple rows
% \usepackage{tabulary}% This is for tables
\usepackage{ragged2e}% This is formatting for long tables
\usepackage[font={small}]{caption}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{U}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}X}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}%C is for central aligned columns and middle aligned, p puts stuff at the bottom, m middles everything.
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}X}%C is for central aligned columns and middle aligned.
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\usepackage{booktabs,dcolumn,caption}
\newcommand{\ra}[1]{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{#1}}%This is for precision tables per property
%

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!ht]
\scriptsize
\catcode`_=13 % Make _ "active"; 
%% This setting expires at end of current group, i.e., at end of "table" environment
\def_{\textunderscore\hspace{0pt}} % "meaning" of "_"
    \centering
    \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
    \begin{tabular}{ C{2.5cm}C{6.5cm}C{3cm}C{3cm}}
    \toprule
      \multicolumn{4}{L{14.5cm}}{``Countries with higher GDP per capita \ldots include \texttt{LOCATION\_SLOT} (around \$\texttt{NUMBER\_SLOT}), and \ldots we find Luxembourg (\$ 122,147).''}  \\ \cmidrule{1-4}

      \multirow{2}{2.5cm}{\textbf{Extracted Region-Value}} & \multirow{2}{6.5cm}{\textbf{KB Properties for Region} } & \multicolumn{2}{C{6cm}}{\textbf{Assigned Label}} \\
      \cmidrule(lr){3-3}
\cmidrule(lr){4-4}
      & & 5\% APE Threshold  & Regular \\\midrule
      Azerbaijan : 7,500 & Azerbaijan: \{population:9,168,000, gdp_nominal_per_capita :1,193, size_of_armed_forces: 81,950, renewable_freshwater_per_capita: 2577 \ldots \} & \textit{no\_region} &  \textit{renewable_freshwater_per_capita}, APE = 0.65\\ \cmidrule{1-4}
      \multicolumn{4}{L{14.5cm}}{
      \textbf{Naive Cost Vector}:\{population:$\infty$, gdp_nominal_per_capita :$\infty$, size_of_armed_forces: $\infty$, renewable_freshwater_per_capita: 0 \ldots \}, \newline    
      \textbf{Cost Vector}:\{population:1221.4, gdp_nominal_per_capita :0.84, size_of_armed_forces: 9.92, renewable_freshwater_per_capita: 0.65 \ldots \}
}  \\ \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Example Distant Supervision}
    \label{tbl:exampledistantsupervision}
    \normalsize
  \end{table}

\end{document}
```

Which results in this:

[image]

Why is my column `KB Properties per Region` appearing `raggedright` instead of centered? My `tabular` columns specify the `C` column type which I define in my preamble as being centered, which is why I don't understand this.

Comment: Your code can't be compiled, due to lines 4-5. There seems to be a missing line.

Comment: the multirow is a parbox so justified text unless you reset it to centering

Comment: @DavidCarlisle try now? I added in a snippet missing. Trying to be as minimal as possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\multirow` is effectively a parbox so implies justified text unless you specify something else, here I just add `\centering` at the start of one cell:

```
& \multirow{2}{6.5cm}{\centering\textbf{KB Properties for Region} } &
```

producing

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can  use `\multirowcell` from `makecell`. I added a small vertical adjustment to take into account the vertical padding of `booktabs` rules:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
 \usepackage{array,ltablex,makecell}% ltablex loads tabularx and longtable also
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize\bfseries}
 \newenvironment{conditions}
 {\par\vspace{\abovedisplayskip}\noindent\begin{tabular}{>{$}l<{$} @{${}={}$} l}}
 {\end{tabular}\par\vspace{\belowdisplayskip}}%This is for descriptions of equations
\usepackage[]{multirow}%Essential for cells in table spanning multiple rows
% \usepackage{tabulary}% This is for tables
\usepackage{ragged2e}% This is formatting for long tables
\usepackage[font={small}]{caption}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{U}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}X}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}%C is for central aligned columns and middle aligned, p puts stuff at the bottom, m middles everything.
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}X}%C is for central aligned columns and middle aligned.
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\usepackage{booktabs,dcolumn,caption}
\newcommand{\ra}[1]{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{#1}}%This is for precision tables per property
%

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!ht]
\scriptsize
\catcode`_=13 % Make _ "active";
%% This setting expires at end of current group, i.e., at end of "table" environment
\def_{\textunderscore\hspace{0pt}} % "meaning" of "_"
    \centering
    \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
    \begin{tabular}{ C{2.5cm}C{6.5cm}C{3cm}C{3cm}}
    \toprule
      \multicolumn{4}{L{14.5cm}}{``Countries with higher GDP per capita \ldots include \texttt{LOCATION\_SLOT} (around \$\texttt{NUMBER\_SLOT}), and \ldots we find Luxembourg (\$ 122,147).''} \\ \cmidrule{1-4}
      \multirow{2}{\linewidth}[-\dimexpr\aboverulesep+\cmidrulewidth\relax]{\textbf{Extracted Region-Value}} & \multirowcell{2}[-\dimexpr\aboverulesep+\cmidrulewidth\relax]{\textbf{KB Properties for Region} } & \multicolumn{2}{C{6cm}}{\textbf{Assigned Label}} \\
      \cmidrule(lr){3-3}
\cmidrule(lr){4-4}
      & & 5\% APE Threshold & Regular \\\midrule
      Azerbaijan : 7,500 & Azerbaijan: \{population:9,168,000, gdp_nominal_per_capita :1,193, size_of_armed_forces: 81,950, renewable_freshwater_per_capita: 2577 \ldots \} & \textit{no\_region} & \textit{renewable_freshwater_per_capita}, APE = 0.65\\ \cmidrule{1-4}
      \multicolumn{4}{L{14.5cm}}{
      \textbf{Naive Cost Vector}:\{population:$∞$, gdp_nominal_per_capita :$∞$, size_of_armed_forces: $∞$, renewable_freshwater_per_capita: 0 \ldots \}, \newline
      \textbf{Cost Vector}:\{population:1221.4, gdp_nominal_per_capita :0.84, size_of_armed_forces: 9.92, renewable_freshwater_per_capita: 0.65 \ldots \}
} \\ \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Example Distant Supervision}
    \label{tbl:exampledistantsupervision}
    \normalsize
  \end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]